# How can I determine in which region a New Zealand city/town/postalcode is located?

Tags: ios, contacts, abaddressbook

I have an app which lists a lot of postal addresses from user-generated data. Where applicable, addresses will be grouped by state, province, or region.

New Zealand postal addresses contain a city and postal code, but no region. Is there any region information available that would let me perform a lookup where I provide the city/town or postal code for a New Zealand street address, and get the region name?

e.g.

```
NSString *region = [nzRegionsForCities objectForKey:@"Dunedin"];
(result is Otago)
```

or

```
NSString *region = [nzRegionsForPostalCodes objectForKey:@"6011"];
(result is Wellington)
```

I'm hoping to avoid the work of creating such a dictionary myself. (I don't know if there are any cities or postal codes that are split among more than one region.) I read the [Postcodes in New Zealand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_New_Zealand) wikipedia page. The first digit of the postal code determines the approximate region but does not give an exact match. The NZ postcode system was introduced in June 2006, so it's possible that the user data will not have correct, current, or any postal codes. Because of this, being able to look up regions for cities is more important than looking up regions for postal codes in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely be able to solve this problem using iOS frameworks. Take a look at the [CLPlacemark](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLPlacemark) and [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder) classes; I used them to build a similar piece of functionality in my app.